# VSCode: Can I have different theme when window is open in Dev container

Tags: visual-studio-code, devcontainer

I have a folder in vscode, that I develop through my host but also through connecting to a Docker container.
In order to easily differentiate the two windows I would like to have different theme for the window without connection to the docker container and the window with the connection.
I have tried using workbench.colorTheme inside the devcontainer.json file but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the next configuration inside devcontainer.json should work ( tested on vscode 1.73 )

```
"settings": {
 "workbench.colorTheme": "Panda Syntax" //replace Panda syntax
},
```

Rebuild container !

Comment: This does not work for me. Tested on Windows, v. 1.74.
`workbench.colorTheme` seems to work only in user settings and in workspace settings with the later overriding the first. Keeping only the .devcontainer one will default to the default theme, not the given one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing the theme in vscode, and then starting the dev container. Theme can be installed through the extensions panel.